# How to perform spatial partitioning in n-dimensions?

Tags: algorithm, math, space-partitioning

I'm trying to design an implementation of Vector Quantization as a c++ template class that can handle different types and dimensions of vectors (e.g. 16 dimension vectors of bytes, or 4d vectors of doubles, etc).

I've been reading up on the algorithms, and I understand most of it:

[here](http://www.data-compression.com/vq.html) and [here](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/Notes/Geckle/525759/lecture8.pdf)

I want to implement the Linde-Buzo-Gray (LBG) Algorithm, but I'm having difficulty figuring out the general algorithm for partitioning the clusters. I think I need to define a plane (hyperplane?) that splits the vectors in a cluster so there is an equal number on each side of the plane.

*[edit to add more info]*
This is an iterative process, but I think I start by finding the centroid of all the vectors, then use that centroid to define the splitting plane, get the centroid of each of the sides of the plane, continuing until I have the number of clusters needed for the VQ algorithm (iterating to optimize for less distortion along the way). The animation in the first link above shows it nicely.

My questions are:

**What is an algorithm to find the plane once I have the centroid?**

**How can I test a vector to see if it is on either side of that plane?**

Comment: When you say "test a vector," I assume you mean "test a point?"  Vectors have no position.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I mean a point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you start with one centroid, then you'll have to split it, basically by doubling it and slightly moving the points apart in an arbitrary direction. The plane is just the plane orthogonal to that direction.

But you don't need to compute that plane.

More generally, the region (i) is defined as the set of points which are closer to the centroid c_i than to any other centroid. When you have two centroids, each region is a half space, thus separated by a (hyper)plane.

How to test on a vector x to see on which side of the plane it is? (that's with two centroids)

Just compute the distance ||x-c1|| and ||x-c2||, the index of the minimum value (1 or 2) will give you which region the point x belongs to.

More generally, if you have n centroids, you would compute all the distances ||x-c_i||, and the centroid x is closest to (i.e., for which the distance is minimal) will give you the region x is belonging to.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand the algorithm, but the second question is easy:

Let's call **V** a vector which extends *from* any point on the plane *to* the point-in-question.  Then the point-in-question lies on the same side of the (hyper)plane as the normal **N** iff **V·N** > 0